# Ajax RSS reader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rss

I am wanting to write a small application that can pull RSS feeds from any RSS feed url. if anyone could give me very basic help on how to achieve this?

im only really starting out in the world on AJAX and this kinda stuff so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT :- I am only trying to do this with Jquery and Ajax, I dont want to use PHP or any other server side code.

Comment: Please remember that unless the server implements Cross Origin Resource Sharing, a url in your AJAX to another server will fail

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific than that. You say that you are stating out with AJAX, are you planing to only use JS and HTML? Or are you using a server side language like PHP? Are you going to write it in plain Javascript - or with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to first create an interface in HTML that allows one to read and subscribe to RSS feeds. You also need to find a way to store the RSS feeds subscribed.

Then you want to use AJAX to get the remote document. I assume you're doing this in jQuery as your tag indicate it does, so you can refer to this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Then, you need to parse the XML that's returned. Check out a RSS tutorial -> http://www.w3schools.com/rss/default.asp and use the jQuery library to parse the data (HTML is kinda like XML, so the jQuery methods still works for XML/RSS) -> http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/

Lastly. Display your data by constructing your interface with JavaScript.